# Advice on structuring an app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, struct, firebase-realtime-database

I am not positive if I am structuring my app correctly. I am using structs for the first time and I am trying to save locations from users and create users using Firebase. I want to display all users only by location. The `Global.refString` gets set from a UIPicker which is hard coded with 6 different locations. `loadUserInfo()` is not returning any information. It worked the first time I tried it but after reopening and closing the app it always returns empty. Im not sure if a struct will get saved each time I open the app. Should I use a different method to accomplish these tasks.

```
private func saveUserInfo(firstLastName: String, user: User!, location: String, biography: String, password: String, phoneNumber: String){
    let locationRef = Global.refString
    let userInfo = ["firstLastName": firstLastName,  "email": user.email!, "password": password, "location": location, "phoneNumber": phoneNumber, "biography": biography, "uid": user.uid, "photoURL": String(describing: user.photoURL!)] as [String : Any]

    let userRef = dataBaseRef.child(locationRef!).child(user.uid)
    userRef.setValue(userInfo) { (error, ref) in
        if error == nil{
            print("USER SAVED")
            self.logIn(email: user.email!, password: password)
        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
}



 func loadUserInfo(){

let locationRef = Global.refString
    let userRef = dataBaseRef.child(locationRef!).child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

    userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let user = Users(snapshot: snapshot)

        if let username = user.name{
            self.nameLabel.text = username
        }

                    if let number = user.phoneNumber{
                        self.phone = Int(number)
                    }
        if let userLocation = user.location{
            self.bioLabel.text = userLocation
        }
            self.storageRef.storage.reference(forURL: imageOld).getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imgData, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let data = imgData {
                            self.avatar.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)

                }
            }  
            )}
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    } 
}



struct Global
 {
static var Location : String!
static var usersListSent
    = [String]()
static var refString: String!
 }
```

Comment: make Users model as singleton and then make a global variable of array of type Users then fetch value and save in that array. this is the way. if this is not your answer then please provide more detail of your code so that we can help you.

Comment: from that global variable of user type you can populate your uipickerview.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Database.database().reference().child(Global.refString).child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in 
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {
            print(snap)
        }
}
```